# Color box environment

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm trying to create a boxing environment for notes but without numbers. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheoremstyle{MyNote}%
{}{}%
{}{}%
{}{}%
{ }%
{\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{{\color{blue}\textbf{\thmname{#1}}}}}
\theoremstyle{MyNote}
\newtheorem{MyNote}{My Note}

\begin{document}
\begin{MyNote}
\lipsum
\end{MyNote}
\end{document}
```

My problem is: how I can control rule thickness of the blue box, vertical and horizontal spaces inside the box? Thanks.

Comment: the same as `\fbox`, set `\fboxrule`and `\fboxsep` to whatever lengths you want (using `\setlength`)

Comment: You don't use `tcolorbox` in your example. Why the tag?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

For thicker border lines just in your box, insert before definition of color box `\setlength\fboxrule{<desired thiknes>}`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheoremstyle{MyNote}%
{}{}%
{}{}%
{}{}%
{ }%
{\setlength\fboxrule{2pt}% <---
 \fcolorbox{blue}{white}{\color{blue}\textbf{\thmname{#1}}}}

\theoremstyle{MyNote}
\newtheorem{MyNote}{My Note}

\begin{document}
\begin{MyNote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{MyNote}
\end{document}
```

produce:

[image]